# Capturing a video with video capture card, opencv

Tags: opencv, breakpoints, video-capture

I am using the following piece of code to capture video from a camera connected to a video capture card.

```
int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(2);    
    if(!cap.isOpened())  
    {
       std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not open camera." << std::endl;
       return -1;
    }
    cv::Mat frame;
    while(1){
       cap >> frame;
       cv::imshow("frame",frame);
       cvWaitKey(10);
    }
}
```

When I use my usb webcams there is no problem and the code works perfectly. However, with the video capture card, I don't see the any video stream! There is no error as well! When I put a break point inside the loop, I can see the video after a couple of iterations. At first I thought this problem is related to the delay and increased the wait time ,i.e., `cvWaitKey(30)` but that also didn't help. The only way it works is with break point! I don't understand what is special about the break point!

Please please help! I have to use this video capture card and want to make an executable file from this code which doesn't work without break points!!! Any comment is appreciated.

NOTE: I am using Windows.

Comment: What kind of camera and "video capture card" are you using? You said you could get first few frames. Are the frames reasonable one with eyes?

Comment: Yes, they are reasonable! And after the first few frames (with breakpoint), the codes works as it should. But without the breakpoint, there is no video. 
About the video capture cards, I am not sure not about the brand. I need to check this.

Comment: It might be timing issue. Between getting two frames, you are showing a frame and waiting 10 milliseconds. That might be a lot for certain camera. Better way is to have a separate thread for image acquisition.

Comment: @user2426357, did you manage to solve this issue?