# Opencv, with video capture card, grabs frames only when a break point is set in the c++ code

Tags: opencv

[Capturing a video with video capture card, opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801160/capturing-a-video-with-video-capture-card-opencv)

The above question pretty much asks what i want to. I have an elgato (elgato video capture http://www.elgato.com/video/video-capture) frame grabber which has USB 2.0 interface. I am trying to use opencv to grab the frames from the elgato frame grabber. Frame grabbing is happening inside a while loop as shown below.

```
grabSuccess        = ( cvGrabFrame (captureDev[0]) == 1 );
frameGrabbed       = (grabSuccess ? cvRetrieveFrame (captureDev[0]) : NULL);    
while (1)
{

    grabSuccess  = ( cvGrabFrame (captureDev[0]) == 1);
    frameGrabbed = (grabSuccess ? cvRetrieveFrame (captureDev[0]) : NULL);
      .
      .
      .
      //some processing
      .
      .
      .
      //show image here
}
```

when I set a break point before the loop and continue the execution after the debugger stops at the break point. Everything works fine( video frames are displayed in cvWindow).
But without the break-point interrupt , I see a blank grayed out window.

Any help would be appreciated.

P:S: I am developing using visual studio 2012 express in windows 8 with opencv 2.3.1 , 
elgato specification are as follows:
 1) Video resolution: 640×480 (4:3) or 640×360 (16:9)
 2) Video format PC Software: H.264 at 1.4 MBit/sec

Comment: What code do you use to display images. Do you use `cv::waitKey(30)` after showing the image? From documentation, `cv::waitKey()` is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes care of event processing.

Comment: also, please move to the c++ api !

Comment: Yes, There is a cvWaitKey(1) after cvShowImage().
@berak, This is just a small part of a big software so switching to c++ will not be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
cv::waitKey(1);
```

After the code line to show the image in a window.

*cv::waitKey()* tells the computer to **wait for some time (1ms here) to render the image in a window**. *cv::waitKey()* is very similar to *_getch()*, which waits for the user to input a key.